# Execute Reader Command is slow

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to run a stored procedure in SQL Server from C#. The stored procedure runs fine in SSMS. It takes 45 seconds to pull these records. However in C# the same call gets a timeout error. What could be the issue here? The XML is a list of Primary Keys from a table in a grid in C#. So it could have 1 line or hundreds of lines. The stored procedure parses it out fine and inserts into a temp table with other data.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
ce.Database.Initialize(force: false);

connection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetAllAccounts", connection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoanList", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoanIdFlagBit",detailModel.activeFlag);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataDtFrom", detailModel.fromDataDt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataDtTo",detailModel.toDataDt)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EffDtFrom",detailModel.fromEffDt)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EffDtTo", detailModel.toEffDt)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JournalDetailId", detailModel.JournalDetailId)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JournalDetailIdList", journalDetailList).DbType = DbType.Xml;

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

My stored procedure code is this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

    @LoanList XML,
    @LoanIdFlagBit BIT = 1, 
    @DataDtFrom SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
    @DataDtTo SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
    @EffDtFrom SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
    @EffDtTo SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
    @JournalDetailId INT = 0,
    @JournalDetailIdList XML = NULL
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Comment: I think you might want `ExecuteNonQuery` instead if the procedure isn't actually returning query results.  Also you should add `using` statements to properly dispose of everything.

Comment: what is the timeout set to on the sql server?

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to read up on [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) instead of using XML to pass a list.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: what happens when you add option(recompile) to stored proc..

Comment: Canonical [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) & as mentioned a table valued paramater (i.e. passing the procedure a DataTable) is likely going to be much more efficient.

Comment: I've added recompile, tried the AddWithValue. None make a difference. My SP does return results however Execute Non Query is still just as slow. My only option is to do TVP instead of XML but that will take sometime as this entire SP is centered around XML and this SP is huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparantly this bit of code I found from a project years ago still works.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetAllAccounts", connection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
**SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);**
```

Then I can assign the values to each parameter returned in a for loop. I don't understand but this cut my time down over 8 minutes down to 45 seconds which is equal to that of the SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Change the CommandTimeout property on your SqlCommand object - The default is 30 seconds;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

I believe the default in SSMS is no timeout

Comment: This does prevent the timeout error but doesn't help with the speed issue. I have no idea why on SSMS its fast but through C# its slow as turtle juice